# Matrix with constant row sum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

It is well known (and shown several times on this site) that if we have a matrix so that each row sums to zero then the matrix must be singular.  I am curious if the following partial converse is known:  if I have a matrix so that every row sums to 1 (or any other nonzero constant, but the same row sum for each row), must the matrix be nonsingular?  I have some computational evidence for this but my guess is I am either missing an easy proof or a counterexample.  Thanks!

Comment: $\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\ 1 & 0\end{array}\right]$?

Comment: If every row of a matrix sums to a constant $k$, then $\lambda=k$ is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $(1,1,\dots,1)^T$. Also recall that the determinant of a matrix is the product of its eigenvalues. So if the rows of a matrix all sum to zero, then zero is an eigenvalue, and hence its determinant is zero, i.e. it is singular. The converse argument doesn't hold, as several counterexamples have shown. Just because the rows sum to $k\neq 0$, does not preclude $0$ from being one of the other eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterexample: consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}
$$
In general, any matrix with repeated rows (or columns) is singular.

Comment: Good point.  What if my rows are all distinct?  (As they are in the problem I have)

Comment: In the $2 \times 2$ case, a singular matrix with constant row sum would necessarily have a repeating row.  Not so in the $3 \times 3$ case.

Comment: Example:
$$
\pmatrix{2&2&2\\6&0&0\\0&3&3}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the example!

Comment: Another (one without repeating columns:)
$$
\pmatrix{
0&1&1\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&2
}
$$